# Simple directive wrapping elements not copying contents

Tags: angularjs

In my quest to master AngularJS I have the following:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='MyApp'>
<head>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>AngularJS - Sandbox</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <my-border>Test text</my-border>    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.myBorder 
{
  color: red;
  border-style: solid;  
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

Javscript:

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

});

myApp.directive('myBorder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="myBorder"></div>'
  };
});
```

Why is the text inside my-border not getting inserted into my directive and what can I do to get it in there? JSBin link: http://jsbin.com/uFISoGUL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [transclude](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) option:

```
myApp.directive('myBorder', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div class="myBorder" ng-transclude></div>',
    transclude: true
  };
});
```

http://jsbin.com/oDOQaXe/1

Comment: Funny I did that before and it didn't work but my original css (which was bad) might have been the culprit.

Comment: @MikeCheel Did you add ng-transclude attribute to the template?

Comment: Yea. I'm thinking it was just bad css (although not sure why the text still wouldn't render but it is working now). Any idea why access to the controller's scope is necessary when there aren't any variables \ model in this example?

Comment: @MikeCheel Well, you will probably need the scope in a regular controller but it won't be necessary if your controller is empty.

Comment: Do you mean just generated by angular (using the ng-controller directive) without a counterpart defined?

Comment: The answer is no to my last comment because I removed the controller implementation and it doesn't work without it.